# The meaning of "the significantly cut mouth"

Tags: meaning

> Mr. Cashell among the batteries coughed slightly to show that he was quite ready to continue his scientific explanations, but I was thinking still of the girl with the rich voice and **the significantly cut mouth**, at whose command I had taken charge of the shop.

This is from "Unprofessional" by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/wireless.htm

I don't understand the meaning of
*the significantly cut mouth*

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: Neither do I, and it isn't mentioned in the notes. I can only guess that _cut_ means _shaped_, like something being cut out, and that the shape of her lips was strikingly beautiful.

Comment: Kate, thank you very much for your suggestion!